# php cygwin ? how to shell_exec

Tags: php, git, bash, cygwin

ok i know this is stupid but atleast im trying :)

```
$result = shell_exec('C:/cygwin/bin/bash.exe /c --login -i git');
var_dump($result);
```

somehow i cant get git command from cygwin, anyone ?

Adam Ramadhan

edit*

it should give

> usage: git [--version]
>   [--exec-path[=GIT_EXEC_PATH]]
>   [--html-path]
>              [-p|--paginate|--no-pager] [--no-replace-objects]
>              [--bare] [--git-dir=GIT_DIR]
>   [--work-tree=GIT_WORK_TREE]
>              [--help] COMMAND [ARGS]
>
> The most commonly used git commands
>   are:    add        Add file contents
>   to the index    bisect     Find by
>   binary search the change that
>   introduced a bug    branch     List,
>   create, or delete branches    checkout
>   Checkout a branch or paths to the
>   working tree    clone      Clone a
>   repository into a new directory
>   commit     Record changes to the
>   repository    diff       Show changes
>   between commits, commit and working
>   tree, etc    fetch      Download
>   objects and refs from another
>   repository    grep       Print lines
>   matching a pattern    init
>   Create an empty git repository or
>   reinitialize an existing one    log
>   Show commit logs    merge      Join
>   two or more development histories
>   together    mv         Move or rename
>   a file, a directory, or a symlink
>   pull       Fetch from and merge with
>   another repository or a local branch
>   push       Update remote refs along
>   with associated objects    rebase
>   Forward-port local commits to the
>   updated upstream head    reset
>   Reset current HEAD to the specified
>   state    rm         Remove files from
>   the working tree and from the index
>   show       Show various types of
>   objects    status     Show the working
>   tree status    tag        Create,
>   list, delete or verify a tag object
>   signed with GPG
>
> See 'git help COMMAND' for more
>   information on a specific command.

as the value

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: geting a git log from cygwin and displaying it to the browser.

Comment: I *think* if you put Cygwin into your PATH variable, you can simply `shell_exec` any installed commands directly, without having to call `bash.exe`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `-i` starts an interactive shell, you don't want that
- `/c` does probably not work
- use `-c command` to run a command, you have `/c --login`
- try `c:\\cygwin\\bin\\git.exe`, or the complete path to git.

Comment: c:\\cygwin\\bin\\git.exe -c git ?